# CSS Transition, Why doesn't collapsing parent div collapse child elements as well?

Tags: html, css

I am new to css transitions, i am trying to collapse a fixed popover div using CSS `transition`. Was able to collapse the outer div successfully, but that did not collapse the elements contained in it. Is this expected? What should i do to completely collapse the "Helpful?" popover?
Here is the plunker
http://plnkr.co/edit/FYbeIe7IY41Ik3LBcf1r?p=preview

Comment: Please add the code to your question. Thanks. A link to some external site is no replacement for that.

Comment: I looked at your CSS and at line 44 you tried to comment it out with `//`. To comment out lines of CSS, you use `/* CSS */`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just give `overflow: hidden` to the fixed element.

Like this:

```
.feedback-popover {
    position: fixed;
    width: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid;
    right: 32px;
    background-color: #dcdcdc;
    z-index: 1030;
    top: 66px;
    max-height: 350px;
    -webkit-transition: max-height 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: max-height 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: max-height 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: max-height 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.feedback-popover-collapse {
    position: fixed;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 50%;
    right: 32px;
    background-color: #dcdcdc;
    z-index: 1030;
    top: 66px;
    max-height: 0px;
    -webkit-transition: max-height 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: max-height 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: max-height 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: max-height 0.5s ease-in-out;
    }
```